# Need help in getting rid of a SORT in a windows function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, sorting, oracle12c

I have this query with a windows function that I have a hard time getting rid of the sort in Oracle. I am by no means an Oracle Expert but my company's application needs to be compatible in both Oracle and SQL Server and we don't really have an Oracle expert so I need help.

Here's is the query in question:

```
SELECT

        A.TYP_0,A.ACCNUM_0,A.NUM_0,A.DUDLIG_0,A.NUMHDU_0

        ,A.DATEVT_0
        ,A.PAYDAT_0
        ,A.BPRTYP_0
        ,A.CPY_0
        ,A.FCY_0
        ,A.BPR_0
        ,A.LIG_0
        ,A.SAC_0
        ,A.SNS_0
        ,A.AMTCUR_0
        ,A.AMTLOC_0
        ,A.PAYCUR_0
        ,A.PAYLOC_0
        ,MIN(DATEVT_0) over (PARTITION BY A.TYP_0,A.ACCNUM_0,A.NUM_0,A.DUDLIG_0 ORDER BY NUMHDU_0 ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS MINFOLLOWING
    FROM SEED.HISTODUD A
    WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATEVT_0) > 1800
```

I have created an index for this just like I did in SQL Server but had to put the INCLUDE fields into the index because that option didn't exist in Oracle

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX X3ARAP_IDX ON SEED.HISTODUD
    (
        TYP_0,
        ,ACCNUM_0
        ,NUM_0
        ,DUDLIG_0
        ,NUMHDU_0
        ,DATEVT_0

        ,PAYDAT_0
        ,BPRTYP_0
        ,CPY_0
        ,FCY_0
        ,BPR_0
        ,LIG_0
        ,SAC_0
        ,SNS_0
        ,AMTCUR_0
        ,AMTLOC_0
        ,PAYCUR_0
        ,PAYLOC_0
    );
```

Here is the execution plan:

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3728420768

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |            |   690 | 71070 |    59   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  WINDOW SORT          |            |   690 | 71070 |    59   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| X3ARAP_IDX |   690 | 71070 |    58   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM INTERNAL_FUNCTION("DATEVT_0"))>1800)
```

We have a customer that has a really huge database and the sort used to create a temporary table but it seems to be no longer doing so (I tried to dropped the index and try the old query but I don't see a temp table on it anymore for some weird reason) but I just can't get rid of the sort.

I tried to replace the MIN by a ROW_NUMBER and get rid of the condition on ROWS to see if that was the issue but I still get the same execution plan.

Comment: Why is the WINDOW SORT predicate an issue? Does the query provide the same results on Oracle and SQL Server? Or is there another problem here? Are statistics up-to-date on this table?

Comment: WINDOW SORT would be caused by the ORDER BY you specified.  It is an integral part of the analytic function you are using.  Why do you believe that needs to be removed?

Comment: Statistics should be up to date.
The query's result is the same on both SQL Server and Oracle.

My query is based on a demo database and I don't have access to the customer's environment.

The speed here seems fine but I can't really play with the customer's database to confirm it is good.

Comment: I was told that it took forever for them to load due a temp table which I got rid of but in SQL Server, the query being slow was due to the SORT so I was trying to get rid of it in Oracle. I googled around and saw some WINDOW NOSORT but I can't manage to get it to come out.

Comment: Slow load time might be caused by the presence of an 18-field index. If that's an issue, drop the index load the table, then create the index.

Comment: We can't do that unfortunately, our application is a BI solution on an existing ERP so I cannot drop the existing tables.

Comment: Oh, and that index was added when I tried tuning it, it wasn't there originally

Comment: Why aren't you just using `lead()`?  It won't change the execution plan but it is more appropriate.

Comment: So Identifier 2 is a bad row and needs to be filtered out. I need to check all subsequent Identifier for that document to see if there is an event date that is smaller than the event date of that row